# Data Table Rendering Issue for 10k records

Tags: angularjs

We are displaying 10,000 rows in table in the browser.

The example given in https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html shows we can show 50,000 records very quickly

We are using Angular with ng-repeat which takes 2 minutes to load the table. We have created 5 columns. In which one of the column has a condition options which will be enabled based on certain conditions for each rows. Whenever we add few options to the button it takes more time

example, edit, delete, view etc., in the action button which is part of a column

We observed whenever we add option along with the ng-repeat with the options takes huge time to render the table.

How to speed up the rendering time ??? Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't compare Angularjs to Datatables for performance.  Angularjs handles the data and the DOM in a completely different manner.  Having conditionals or function calls in an `ng-repeat` will cause the DOM to be iterated over multiple times for each row, which only gets exponentially worse the more rows you have.  If you **must** use Angularjs to render 10k rows, you should ensure that your array has the exact data you want to output and no calculations should be done in the HTML at all.  If you need more help, please post a [mcve] showing your HTML structure for review.

Comment: Agree with @Claies. Look for DataTables serverside solution. Even if you were not using angular, serverside is the only sane way when you have more than 3000k records. You should never render out with angular, i.e ng-repeat if you have more than 1000 records (optimistic estimate)